# Self Destructing Post?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm currently using 'socialization' and 'acts_as_commentable_with_threading' gems. I really need help on creating self-destructing threads that implode after a specified period of time. For example: Form Discussion "How to program a droid with Arduino?" => Destroy after 10 days with timer. Anyone have an idea or method of implementation?

I really can use the help.

Comment: You need a background job to do this. Write a rake task which is to find all records which are to be removed and removes those. Then set up cronjob to fire this rake task every day

Comment: I will look into after I setup socialization which doesn't have much documentation to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually need to "self-destruct" anything. Your controller simply needs to refuse to serve posts that are more than 10 days old. You should just check, and conditionally render a 404 if the post has aged away.

Comment: Sounds good. Will the record delete from the database? That's the kind of result that I'm trying to get. Sort of like Snapchat with text.

Comment: It could, if you wanted it do, but again, there is no reason to actually delete the record. It would be better if you keep it so you have some record that it existed at some point.